# How to configure .pac file for proxy in macOS

Tags: network, proxy, macos

I have a .pac file from our hosted web server for proxy. It is working fine for Windows and I am able to access site allowed by proxy.

However, I use the same link of .pac file in my macOS, then it doesn't work at all. 
I simply add in **Proxies** -> **Automatic Proxy Configuration** and point the URL of .pac. Do I have to do any additional step for .pac working?

I saw the post for a similar kind of [problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/957519/why-does-file-users-username-library-proxy-pac-not-work-in-macos)  but it didn't help me. Do we need any further modification somewhere besides pointing URL in Proxy Configuration?

**macOS version: 10.14 and 10.15**

Comment: Any solution from an expert who has been working on such things.